# PaperJs errors are not understable

Tags: javascript, html, paperjs

Getting lots of issues with Paper.js. Doing Colt Steele's Web Developer Bootcamp on Udemy. I'm on Section 19. Currently trying to make a Patatap clone.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Colors Sound</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/index.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/paper-full.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.9/howler.core.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
                var newCircle = new Path.Circle(new Point(50, 50),50);
                newCircle.fillColor = "red";
                var keyData = {
                    a: { sound = new Howl({
                    src: [assets/sounds/clay.mp3]
                }),
                    color: 'red'
                }
            }
                function onKeyDown(e){
                    if(keyData[e.key]){
                       var maxPoint = new Point(max.width.size, max.height.size);
                       var randomPoint = Point.Random();
                       var point = maxPoint * randomPoint ;
                       var circle = new Path.Circle(point, 50);
                       circle.fillColor = keyData[e.key].color;
                       keyDAta[e.key].sound.play();
            }
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
        </body>
        </html>
```

and these are the errors in the Chrome Console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:14)
    at raise (paper-full.js:14884)
    at unexpected (paper-full.js:15524)
    at parseObj (paper-full.js:16002)
    at parseExprAtom (paper-full.js:15957)
    at parseExprSubscripts (paper-full.js:15888)
    at parseMaybeUnary (paper-full.js:15874)
    at parseExprOps (paper-full.js:15840)
    at parseMaybeConditional (paper-full.js:15827)
    at parseMaybeAssign (paper-full.js:15813)
    at parseExpression (paper-full.js:15802)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of, you can very easily check for errors by using diffchecker with Colt's code against your own.

Second, at first glance, your error is at

```
sound = new Howl
```

It should be

```
sound: new Howl
```

As you're working with objects, which use key/value pairs

Comment: I checked the difference, and i changed somethings like  
src: [assets/sounds/clay.mp3]
it was URL :...
i thought the problem is in the library itself that's why i'm confused